# Delete Excel Rows in all sheets with Specific Contents using xlwings

Tags: xlwings

I have a workbook with rows to delete tagged in as "Delete" in column A in all sheets of the workbook.

How can i delete these rows using xlwings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have 3 worksheets in my file where rows to delete are marked as Delete in column A. using xlwings how can i delete such rows from all 3 sheets.
For example in sheet 1 cell A4, A7, A9,A10 contains text ""Delete". how can i delete rows 7, 7, 9 and 10?